# Reusing List for DropDownMenu in Kotlin Causes a repeating entry with empty space

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a dropdown box using my list `options` and then select a choice. My next dropdown includes the same list, but is adding the first option in the list and a small blank space under it. When choosing a choice for my third dropdown list, it does it twice.
The previous dropdowns will do it now too. I also have the issue where the first box will populate the other boxes as a new choice.

[image: GIF of error in dropdown menu]

Here is the source code:

```kotlin
// create list to re-use
val options = rememberSaveable {
    listOf(
        "Hindsight", "Ready When You Are", "The Way We Are", "Blow",
        "Blurry Eyed", "Better Off Dead", "Old Habits", 
        "ShallowGrave", "Bullet In The Head", "Dead Weight", 
        "Insomniac", "Follow Me Down", "On My Own", "Bleed You Dry", 
        "Reflections", "Mirrors", "Nowhere Left"
            )
    }
    // sending variables to composable               
    ExposedDropdownMenuSongs(
        songVar,
        songVarChanged = { newSongVar ->
            songVar = newSongVar
            },
        options = options,
        selectedOptions,
        songVar2,
        songVarChanged2 = { newSongVar ->
            songVar2 = newSongVar
            },
        songVar3,
        songVarChanged3 = { newSongVar ->
            songVar3 = newSongVar
            },
    )
}

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @Composable
    fun ExposedDropdownMenuSongs(
        songVar: String, songVarChanged: (newSongVar: String) -> Unit,
        options: List<String>,
        selectedOptions: MutableState<List<String>>,
        songVar2: String, songVarChanged2: (newSongVar: String) -> Unit,
        songVar3: String, songVarChanged3: (newSongVar: String) -> Unit,
    ) {
        var expanded by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }
        val currentSelected = selectedOptions.value.toMutableList()
        var choice1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        var choice2 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        Column {
            ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
                expanded = expanded,
                onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextInputService provides null) {
                    TextField(
                        readOnly = true,
                        value = songVar,
                        onValueChange = { selected ->
                            if (options.contains(selected)) {
                                currentSelected.add(songVar)
                            } else {
                                currentSelected.remove(songVar)
                            }
                            selectedOptions.value = currentSelected
                        },
                        label = { Text("Song1:") },
                        modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
                    )
                }
                ExposedDropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                ) {
                    options.forEach { selectionOption ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            text = { Text(text = selectionOption) },
                            onClick = {
                                songVarChanged(selectionOption)
                                choice1 = selectionOption
                                expanded = false
                            },
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            //create new box with same list if condition met
            if (options.contains(songVar)) {
                ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
                    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextInputService provides null) {
                        TextField(
                            readOnly = true,
                            value = songVar2,
                            onValueChange = { selected ->
                                if (options.contains(selected)) {
                                    currentSelected.add(songVar)
                                } else {
                                    currentSelected.remove(songVar)
                                }
                                selectedOptions.value = currentSelected
                            },
                            label = { Text("Song2:") },
                            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
                        )
                    }
                    ExposedDropdownMenu(
                        expanded = expanded,
                        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                    ) {
                        // filter out previous option from list
                        options.filter{
                            it != choice1
                        }.forEach { selectionOption2 ->
                            DropdownMenuItem(
                                text = { Text(text = selectionOption2) },
                                onClick = {
                                    songVarChanged2(selectionOption2)
                                    choice2 = selectionOption2
                                    expanded = false
                                },
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // create third box if condition is met
            if (options.contains(songVar2)) {
                ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
                ) {
                    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextInputService provides null) {
                        TextField(
                            readOnly = true,
                            value = songVar3,
                            onValueChange = { selected ->
                                if (options.contains(selected)) {
                                    currentSelected.add(songVar3)
                                } else {
                                    currentSelected.remove(songVar3)
                                }
                                selectedOptions.value = currentSelected
                            },
                            label = { Text("Song2:") },
                            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
                        )
                    }
                    ExposedDropdownMenu(
                        expanded = expanded,
                        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                    ) {
                        options.filter{
                            it != choice1 && it != choice2
                        }.forEach { selectionOption ->
                            DropdownMenuItem(
                                text = { Text(text = selectionOption) },
                                onClick = {
                                    songVarChanged3(selectionOption)
                                    expanded = false
                                },
                            )
                        }
...
```

I am using `options` to tell the dropdown what to use, but I can't see where or if I change it within the code.

Comment: That's a lot for someone unfamiliar with your code to sift through. [Debug](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) your app using breakpoints and logs to trace the flow and narrow down where the issue is happening.

Comment: @dominicoder I have cleaned it up a good bit. The length is because I repeat a lot of code with minor changes, but am unsure if it is relevant or not. Debugging hasn't yielded any answers so far

Answer (score 0):

I moved things around and decided to make an entire new composable for each dropdown menu I needed. I added an `if` loop to my Activity instead:

```kotlin
if (options.contains(songVar)) {
    ExposedDropdownMenuSongs2(
    songVar,
    options = options,
    selectedOptions = selectedOptions,
    songVar2 = songVar2,
    songVarChanged2 = { newSongVar2 ->
        songVar2 = newSongVar2
    },
    songVar3 = songVar3,
    songVarChanged3 = { newSongVar3 ->
        songVar3 = newSongVar3
    }
    )
}
```

And changed values in my composable to be according variables.